# Java depth-first search maze generating alogrithm gets stuck

Tags: java, depth-first-search, maze

I have a maze generating algorithm working with depth-first search.
It first generates a raw maze which looks like this:
[image: raw maze]
Then it creates the maze using this algorithm: http://www.mazeworks.com/mazegen/mazetut/index.html 
The result looks like this:
[image: result]
The red pixel marks the goal, the green one the start.
It gets stuck at the goal and jumps back and forth until it thinks it finished.
 
Maze Generator source:

```
public Maze generate(int width, int height) {
    Maze maze = getRawMaze(width, height);

    List<Point> cellStack = new LinkedList<Point>();
    int totalAirCells = maze.getTotalAirCells();
    Point currentCell = maze.getRandomAirCell(ran);
    maze.setCellTypeAt(currentCell, Maze.CellType.START);       
    int visitedCells = 1;

    while(visitedCells<totalAirCells) {
        Point[] unvisitedNeighbors = getUnvisitedNeighbors(maze, currentCell);
        if(unvisitedNeighbors.length!=0) {
            System.out.println("Go Foward");
            Point newCell = unvisitedNeighbors[ran.nextInt(unvisitedNeighbors.length)];
            maze.connect(newCell, currentCell);
            cellStack.add(currentCell);
            currentCell = newCell;
            visitedCells++;
        }else {
            System.out.println("Go Back");
            Point recentCell = cellStack.get(cellStack.size()-1);
            cellStack.remove(cellStack.size()-1);
            currentCell = recentCell;
        }
    }

    maze.setCellTypeAt(currentCell, Maze.CellType.GOAL);

    return maze;
}

public Point[] getUnvisitedNeighbors(Maze maze, Point p) {
    List<Point> unvisitedNeighbors = new ArrayList<Point>();
    Point[] neighbors = maze.getNeighbors(p);
    for(Point n : neighbors) {
        if(maze.getSurroundingWalls(n)==4)unvisitedNeighbors.add(n);
    }
    return unvisitedNeighbors.toArray(new Point[unvisitedNeighbors.size()]);
}
```

additional source:

```
public int getSurroundingWalls(Point p) {
    if(getCellTypeAt(p)==CellType.AIR) {
        int walls = 0;
        if(getCellTypeAt(new Point(p.x+1, p.y))==CellType.WALL)walls++;
        if(getCellTypeAt(new Point(p.x-1, p.y))==CellType.WALL)walls++;
        if(getCellTypeAt(new Point(p.x, p.y+1))==CellType.WALL)walls++;
        if(getCellTypeAt(new Point(p.x+1, p.y-1))==CellType.WALL)walls++;
        return walls;
    }else return -1;
}

public Point[] getNeighbors(Point p) {
    Point[] neighbors = new Point[4];
    neighbors[0] = new Point(p.x+2, p.y);
    neighbors[1] = new Point(p.x-2, p.y);
    neighbors[2] = new Point(p.x, p.y+2);
    neighbors[3] = new Point(p.x, p.y-2);
    return neighbors;
}

public void connect(Point a, Point b) {
    if((a.x==b.x-2)&&(a.y==b.y))setCellTypeAt(new Point(a.x+1, a.y), CellType.AIR);
    else if((a.x==b.x+2)&&(a.y==b.y))setCellTypeAt(new Point(a.x-1, a.y), CellType.AIR);
    else if((a.x==b.x)&&(a.y==b.y-2))setCellTypeAt(new Point(a.x, a.y+1), CellType.AIR);
    else if((a.x==b.x)&&(a.y==b.y+2))setCellTypeAt(new Point(a.x, a.y-1), CellType.AIR);
}

public Point getRandomAirCell(Random ran) {
    List<Point> airCells = new LinkedList<Point>();
    for(int x = 0; x<getWidth(); x++) {
        for(int y = 0; y<getHeight(); y++){
            Point p = new Point(x, y);
            if(getCellTypeAt(p)==Maze.CellType.AIR)airCells.add(p);
        }
    }
    return airCells.get(ran.nextInt(airCells.size()));
}

public int getTotalAirCells() {
    int airCells = 0;
    for(int x = 0; x<getWidth(); x++) {
        for(int y = 0; y<getHeight(); y++){
            if(getCellTypeAt(new Point(x, y))==Maze.CellType.AIR)airCells++;
        }
    }
    return airCells;
}
```

Why does the algorithm not finish the maze?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Does it throw an error message? If not, what does the standard output look like? Have it print out the values of `visitedCells` and `cellStack.size()`

Comment: What's the reason to have the `getSurroundingWalls()` function? As far as I can see, you use it just to check if the cell has FOUR walls around it, so you can tell if it is connected to the maze already or not. If that's right, I'd suggest you to simplify the code: initialize all cells' typ to CellType.UNUSED instead of AIR - then you just test the cell type to see if it can be connected to the maze (and then change its type to AIR).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check `getSurroundingWalls()`, the fourth point checked is `p.x+1, p.y-1` but I suppose it should be `p.x, p.y-1`.